# How to avoid in-responsiveness of in-memory caching process triggered due to OutOFMemory Error

Tags: java, redis, out-of-memory, etcd, in-memory

Assume, there is a java process which acts as a in-memory cache server and stores data into it.
There are multiple clients which continuously can push data of any size. In case client tries to push data more than what is available in jvm heap size of server, it throws OOM error and eventually process goes into in-responsive state.

I am sure this is not unique/specialized requirement. Problem simply boils down to - **How to handle this kind of scenario gracefully?** Caching server (jvm) should somehow instead of throwing OOM error, it should just reject the request itself?

*Note - limitation cannot be put in client request payload size.*

**How these things (huge payload) are managed in redis or any other in-memory caching server?**

Comment: The case of "huge payload" is not worse than "many small payloads"; in fact, many small payloads are likely to be more problematic for JVM: they are promoted to "old gen", they are all alive, full GC is triggered on them and it has to traverse a lot of objects. For this reason most caching solutions in Java offer options to store cached objects in off-heap memory.

Comment: As to the "huge" payloads, I do not think that general-purpose caching solutions are tailored for that case, or you should be more specific about how "huge" and how many of those you expect. Also, you should not assume that you can just throw an in-memory cache working on 1 machine at the problem and it will just magically work. Physical limits of memory and disk are there; depending on the specifics of your problem, you might need an on-disk solution or storage distributed across several nodes.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your point. I don't want to accomodate request which are leading to OOM error. May be i will simplify my question.  Just wanted to have an http server (Rest) which can check from incoming request if that request can be fullfilled or not? And this checking should happen before even payload gets memory allocation in heap. May be by just looking at 'content-length' header. But this iam not sure if it will work

Comment: It's really up to you and depends on the details of the system. E.g. you can make a decision to reject requests that do not carry "Content-Length" or where "Content-Length" is larger than a certain threshold. Will it work in your case? Only you can tell.

Comment: Reading "Content-Length" doesn't make sure that payload has not been loaded in the server. Because by that time receiving server endpoint might have already loaded the body payload.

Comment: "Content-Length" is meant to allow making decisions prior to reading the body, so any major technology _allows_ to do that. Of course you can misuse it. E.g. if you map the body to a string parameter (via JAX-RS, Spring MVC etc.), it will be read in full. If you work with the raw `HttpServletRequest` (reading the body from the input stream that you receive from it), or if you insert your own `javax.servlet.Filter` or `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor` or whatever thing your technology supports, the payload will not be read until _your_ code reads it explicitly.

Comment: ...and also your code can be written in a way to not read more than N bytes, no matter what.